# snakemake covering old output file

Tags: conda, pipeline, snakemake

I used '*snakemake*' to build up a pipeline and run it, got some output files, and when I run the pipeline in the second time, it will restart from the very beginning step and even there has the output file of the step, it still runs it from the very beginning and covers the old file.

here is the command line:

```
snakemake --snakefile {snakefile} --jobs {jobs} --rerun-incomplete --nolock  --use-conda  --conda-prefix {conda_prefix} {add_args} {args}
```

is anyone knows what happened??

thanks

Comment: Seeing the code will help debugging in this case. [A minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is recommended.